# How do you throw form error on page load after returning from php validation?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a form to make it simple:

```
<?php $final_auto="required" ?>
<form name="Form" action="mydomain.com/form.php?action=send" method="post">
<textarea name="final_thoughts" <?echo $final_auto; ?>><?php echo $final_thoughts; ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

As you can see if the textarea is empty it will throw an error.  However this is done on client side, now when the form is submitted I need to double check on the server side:

```
if (isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['final_thoughts']) && (!empty($HTTP_POST_VARS['final_thoughts']))) {
$final_thoughts = tep_db_prepare_input(isset($HTTP_POST_VARS['final_thoughts']));
}else{
$final_auto = "autofocus required aria-invalid=\"true\"";
}
```

So we check to see if there is a value for posted form data $HTTP_POST_VARS['final_thoughts'].
If there is a value then we store it in the variable $final_thoughts.

Now this is where I need help with.
If there is no value then we are going to store in $final_auto attributes for the field which are autofocus(so when the form reloads it will automatically go to that field), again keeping it required.

All of this works, what I can not figure out is when the form reloads, and it autofocuses to the field, I want it to throw the default error message tool tip with the ! icon image.

From what I have read you can add the aria-invalid="true" attribute.  However everything works with the exception of the error message tool tip popping up.

Now the form is just a simple form for demonstrations, however my form has way more fields than just this one.

Any and all help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for different keywords and going deep into several explanations I finally put 2 and 2 together.

The solution is to use onfocus and reportValidity together.

```
$final_auto = "autofocus required onfocus=\"this.reportValidity()\"";
```

This will take you right to the field on the form and put focus on the field and then that triggers the onfocus event which is set to trigger the error as if you hit the submit button without submission, all it does is check the field only.